# Safety of powering 5V circuit of 240V main outlet using adapter

Tags: arduino, power-supply, attiny

I have created a circuit using an ATTiny that will need constant power. I was thinking of using one of the 240V to 5V USB adapters that come with many phones to power this circuit.

Will I need to put a voltage regulator into my circuit or is such an adapter sufficiently stable/protected, that I can run the 5V directly into the circuit.

Also does the amp rating make a difference for this, as some output 1A and others 2A?

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting my answer, it is a good idea to wait a while to see what others might say.  Some people will skip over a question if they see it already has a accepted answer, so you won't know what other answers you might have gotten.

Comment: Yeah, I recommend you wait a day or so to give everyone accross the world a chance, or after you get 3 answers.  Just don't forget to come back after a day, look over the answers, and pick one if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a general purpose USB "charger", then it should be fine.  Since those don't know what device will be hooked up, they have to provide regulated 5 V as USB devices expect.  If it's a charger for a specific device, then it might play some games, but even then likely not.

You can always check this.  Use a voltmeter to read the output power voltage.  That should be close to 5 V.  Then load it with 1/2 amp or so and verify that the voltage doesn't dip much.  A 10 Ω resistor accross 5 V will draw 1/2 amp.  Note also that it will dissipate 2.5 W, but you only need to hold it there just long enough to watch what the voltmeter does.  A little 1/4 W or 1/8 W resistor might blow up quickly, but a 2 W resistor will be fine for a few seconds.

The current rating only tells you how much the charger *can* deliver.  It is up to the device what it actually takes.  A 2 A charger is therefore a superset of a 1 A charger.  If your device only needs 1 A, then both will be fine.  Note that real USB only guarantees 500 mA, and that is after some negotation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes I mean a general purpose charger. Thank you also for clearing up the amp rating. My device will use less than 1A, so either one will work fine.

Comment: If you need larger amounts of power, any port compatible with with the Battery Charging Specification 1.2 can provide 5A of current.  I saw a recent proposal to increase USB power to 100W but don't know if there's any traction behind it or not.